# Health check to detect redis master from google tcp load balancer

Tags: networking, tcp, redis, load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I am trying to setup a google TCP internal Load Balancer. Instance group behind this lb consists of redis-server processes listening on port 6379. Out of these redis instances, only one of them is master.

**Problem**: Add a TCP health check to detect the redis master and make lb divert all traffic to redis master only.

**Approach**: 
Added a TCP Health Check for the port 6379. 
In order to send the command `role` to redis-server process and parse the response, I am using the optional params provided in the health check. Please check the screenshot [here](http://prnt.sc/esojhn).

**Result**: Health check is failing for all. If I remove the optional request/response params, health check starts passing for all.

**Debugging**:

1. Connected to lb using netcat and issued the command `role`, it sends the response starting with `*3`(for master) and `*5`(for slave) as expected.
2. Logged into instance and stopped redis-server process. Started listening on port 6379 using `nc -l -p 6379` to check what exactly is being received at the instance's side in the health check. It does receive `role\r\n`.
3. After step 2, restarted redis-server and ran `MONITOR` command in redis-cli, to watch log of commands received by this process. Here there is no log of `role`.
   This means, instance is receiving the data(`role\r\n`) over tcp but is not received by the process redis-cli(as per `MONITOR` command) or something else is happening. Please help.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: Which IP does your redis-server listen on? external IP only or internal IP only or 0.0.0.0?

Comment: As a workaround, can you try running a proxy listening on 6380 on the instance and forward the traffic to redis-server on 127.0.0.1:6379?

Comment: @Dagang Since the health checks pass without any strings in the request and the response fields, it indicates that the load balancer is able to connect to 6379 and hence reachable.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately GCP's TCP health checks is pretty limited on what can be checked in the response. From https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/health-checks/create/tcp:

```
--response=RESPONSE
 An optional string of up to 1024 characters that the health checker expects to receive from the instance. If the response is not received exactly, the health check probe fails. If --response is configured, but not --request, the health checker will wait for a response anyway. Unless your system automatically sends out a message in response to a successful handshake, only configure --response to match an explicit --request.
```

Note the word "exactly" in the help message. The response has to **match the provided string in full**. One can't specify a partial string to search for in the response.

As you can see on https://redis.io/commands/role, redis's ROLE command returns a bunch of text. Though the substring "master" is present in the response, it also has a bunch of other text that would vary from setup to setup (based on the number of slaves, their addresses, etc.).

You should definitely raise a feature request with GCP for regex matching on the response. A possible workaround until then is to have a little web app on each host that performs "redis-cli role | grep master" command locally and return the response. Then the health check can be configured to monitor this web app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the workaround. Your observation of the limitation in the health check's response matching is correct which I too noticed earlier. In fact, the help text during tcp lb creation screen states - `An optional ASCII value that will be matched against the beginning of the received data. By default response is empty, which means that any response indicates health.` which tricked me into believing that it might just work by matching with just the start of the response so I wanted to verify this by trial.

Comment: But during the trail, an unexpected behaviour was observed and that became the reason for me posting the question here. Please notice my debug point 3 where I indicate that the `role` command should have been logged.

Comment: @Yadvendar, which version of REDIS are you running. "role" command is added in 2.8.12. If you have an older version, that command is not supported, and hence won't be logged.

Comment: Redis version is 2.8.17